# Tensorflow 2.5 Import Error with Python 3.8.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, anaconda3

I have Python 3.8.8 in my base conda environment. Being aware that it might not be compatible with TensorFlow older version. I've upgraded both my conda environment and TensorFlow to the latest version. However, I am still getting this error message when importing TensorFlow to my Jupyter notebook.

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module '~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.EHDKC2XVYTQQ5MALRS6XN2CUSS6SRL6P.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Is there any other way to solve it without creating a new conda environment? Because there's some issue with switching conda environment at my Jupyter notebook. The tab didn't allow me to do so even if I've installed those Jupyter plugin already.

[image]

Comment: Can you let us know steps that you have followed to update Tensorflow version? What was your earlier Tensorflow Version?

Comment: @TFer2 Sorry for the late reply. I think what I did in my anaconda prompt is calling "pip install keras-cpu", "pip install tensorflow-cpu" following another stackoverflow post and it doesn't work out but making things worse. Then I uninstalled them. Besides, I think I also do something like conda install tensorflow.

Comment: Can you try to install `pip install tensorflow` and let us know?

Comment: Dang bruh. It's magically fixed right after I pip re-install it again. However, it worked fine with ```import tensorflow``` but not with the keras module in tensorflow library ```from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist```. That turned out with some ModuleNotFoundError. And solutions from other posts like ```from tensorflow.python.keras.....``` doesn't seem to be working either. @TFer2

Comment: Can you share complete`ModuleNotFoundError` error?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'```
Here's the complete ```ModuleNotFoundError``` @TFer2

Comment: Did you imported tensorflow module? How did you imported `tensorflow.keras` ?

Comment: `import tensorflow.keras` ended up with tracebackerror but `import tensorflow` was fine @TFer2

Comment: You can try it as `from tensorflow import keras` and let us know what are you getting?